# How to add dependencies to fx?

Tags: fuchsia

When I tried to set the building target(`workstation.arm64`), I got this error:

```sh
ERROR Unresolved dependencies.
//:additional_cache_packages(//build/toolchain/fuchsia:arm64)
  needs //src/chromium:chrome_browser(//build/toolchain/fuchsia:arm64)
```

How can I add `chromium:chrome_browser` to fx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies like this are resolved automatically by the GN build system. The error you are seeing is because GN cannot find the package required by that product in the source tree.

More specifically, the `workstation` product [currently depends](https://cs.opensource.google/fuchsia/fuchsia/+/main:products/workstation.gni;l=67) on the `//src/chromium:chrome_browser` package targets, which are currently only [available in the build graph](https://cs.opensource.google/fuchsia/fuchsia/+/main:src/chromium/generate_chromium_targets.gni;l=150) for `x64` targets. You can verify this by checking if you can successfully call `fx set workstation.x64`.

Regarding workstation support on `arm64`, I would recommend [filing an issue](https://bugs.fuchsia.dev/p/fuchsia/issues/entry?template=Fuchsia+Default) so the team can determine if support can be added to the build or if the supported CPUs for workstation need to be documented.